# Optional where clause using ISNULL

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have stored procedures take multiple parameters (up to 7 or 8 in some cases) to be used to filter down the result set.  These parameters are optional (default `NULL`).  All non-NULL values passed in are to be used in the filter (i.e. it's boolean `and` instead of boolean `or`).

These queries usual end up looking like this...

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE (@Param1 IS NULL OR (@Param1 IS NOT NULL AND [Field1] = @Param1))
      AND (@Param2 IS NULL OR (@Param2 IS NOT NULL AND [Field2] = @Param2))
      AND (@Param3 ...
```

I'm aware that this is very inefficient, but due to the number of parameters it just isn't possible split them into individual queries.

So instead I tried doing the following...

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Field1] = ISNULL(@Param1, [Field1])
      AND [Field2] = ISNULL(@Param2, [Field2])
      AND [Field3] ...
```

However, the problem occurs when a field contains `NULL` and therefore the `=` operator simply doesn't work.

Is there a simple and efficient way of doing this so I can have a single query, using multiple "filter" parameters?  I'd prefer not to use dynamic SQL if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could simplify your initial SQL down to this, since you've already tested for `NULL` in each clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE (@Param1 IS NULL OR [Field1] = @Param1)
      AND (@Param2 IS NULL OR [Field2] = @Param2)
      AND (@Param3 ...
```

This isn't necessarily inefficient.  You would probably be wise to check for parameter sniffing issues if you routinely pass in parameter combinations that lead to wildly different execution plans.

Comment: Yeah, fair point, I think it's a hang over from when the parameters used to be actual values instead of nulls... so they used to be things like `AND (@Param1 = '' OR (@Param1 <> '' AND [Field1] = @Param1))` for example. As SQL doesn't do short-circuiting in the same way as C# `&&` or VB.NET `AndAlso`, I thought it would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using "is null" is to do this comparison:

```
where coalesce(Field1, @Param1, '') = coalesce(@Param1, Field1, '') . . .
```

If one of Field1 or @Param1 have values, then the two COALESCEs return that value.  Only if both are NULL do you get to the third arguemnt.

It so happens that you can convert `''` to any type, so that is also covered.  However, the use of the function tends to preclude the user of indexes.